# How to resolve Google Yolo "noCredentialsAvailable: No credential is available for the current user." issue

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, oauth-2.0, yolo

I am implementing Google Yolo into one of my project. As I required a popup on the right top corner which shows me Google account to sign up and user can directly login form that.  I tried Google Yolo for first time. I implement my code similar to [GitHub](https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline/blob/master/google-yolo-iframe.html)! and this didn't worked. it always gave me "noCredentialsAvailable: No credential is available for the current user.".

I tried to find this issue over internet but there is no solution. Even all google pages related this are end with 404 error. All Google references regarding Google Yolo are not found. **Is Google end up with Yolo?**

I added all things. I got that popup on various websites like https://www.wego.co.in/. Also signin with Google button is working prefect on same project. its opening new popup for Google account and reverting data.

Comment: Have You found Any Solution ? Because I have same issue. And need a solution.

Comment: No I didn't find anything on it. but this that google have stopped this service

Comment: Thanks for reply. Recently google  introduced one tap login service with updated version. here is the reference : https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/html-reference